# What limits the maximum allowable current of a power LED?

Tags: led

I wonder what it is that limits how much current can flow through a power LED. If the heat removal is managed properly how large can the current get? Why 45x45 mil size LED chips are rated 3W (700mA) but smaller ones 350mA? 
I've got an LED module, it has 9 45x45mil LED chips (It is RGB), I want the maximum light intensity possible, what is the maximum safe current? I don't care if the life is shortened to half or one third compared to if it were drived at 350ma (the manufacturer rated current).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things that determines the LED lifetime is the junction temperature (the temperature of the LED die inside the package). Then it's a matter of how fast you can remove heat from that, given the thermal resistance between the junction and the pad where the heatsink attaches (upon which you have no control, and which may be lower for larger LEDs).

Some manufacturers have published data on temperature and current vs. lifetime which shows that indeed if you accept some reduction in lifetime and have proper heatsinking you can drive their LEDs at 2x the rated current.

See for instance the [OSRAM Dragon reliability information](http://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic8/00165204_0.pdf/Reliability%20of%20the%20DRAGON%20Product%20Family.pdf). Note how the lifetime drops smoothly from 100,000 to 20,000 hours with increasing current/temperature and then suddenly to 0 hours when you exceed the maximal temperature (fig. 5). Note also how this depends on the LED color (fig. 5 vs fig.7), with blue/green/white LEDs much more fragile than yellow/red LEDs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
So as you say larger chip size has better heat transfer because it has larger area so lager currents can pass over it.So if I keep the heat sink temperature constant if I double the power the junction temperature doubles?

Comment: The temperature *difference* between the heatsink and the junction will double.